# about the formal parameters of the String call to the foldRight function in Scala? Why (Nil: List[A])?

Tags: scala

[doubt code about string call foldRight](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gj3jd.png)

Is the formal parameter of this code a shorthand?

```scala
val list = "abc".foldRight(Nil: List[Int])((x, acc) => x :: acc)
```

If so, I understand

```scala
val nilList: List[Int] = Nil
    val list = "abc".foldRight(nilList) { (x, acc) => x :: acc  }
```

Comment: It is not a shorthand, it is only a way to help the complier to understand the final type of folded result. Indeed, in general, the type inference start from left to right. So, when the compiler encounter Nil (without the type) it infers that the resulting type of fold should be List[Nothing]. So, using : List[Int] you tell to the compiler that the final result will be a List[Int] (it is type safe because Nothing is a bottom type and List in covariant). BTW I prefer to use `List.empty[Int]` it is more understandable for me.

Comment: oh,I understand,thank you!